# Moving something rotated on a custom pivot Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I've created an arm with a custom pivot in Unity which is essentially supposed to point wherever the mouse is pointing, regardless of the orientation of the player. Now, this arm looks weird when pointed to the side opposite the one it was drawn at, so I use `SpriteRenderer.flipY = true` to flip the sprite and make it look normal. I also have a weapon at the end of the arm, which is mostly fine as well. Now the problem is that I have a "FirePoint" at the end of the barrel of the weapon, and when the sprite gets flipped the position of it doesn't change, which affects particles and shooting position. Essentially, all that has to happen is that the Y position of the FirePoint needs to become negative, but Unity seems to think that I want the position change to be global, whereas I just want it to be local so that it can work with whatever rotation the arm is at. I've attempted this:

```
if (rotZ > 40 || rotZ < -40) {
    rend.flipY = true;
    firePoint.position = new Vector3(firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y * -1, firePoint.position.z);
} else {
    rend.flipY = false;
    firePoint.position = new Vector3(firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y * -1, firePoint.position.z);
}
```

But this works on a global basis rather than the local one that I need. Any help would be much appreciated, and I hope that I've provided enough information for this to reach a conclusive result. Please notify me should you need anything more. Thank you in advance, and have a nice day!

Comment: considered using `localPosition` ?

Comment: Thank you, this helped me very much. Please consider putting it into an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: for easier solution check my answer as well. and vote up

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RotateAround()` to get desired behaviour instead of flipping stuff around. Here is sample code:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform pivotTransform; // need to assign in inspector
    void Update() 
    {
        transform.RotateAround(pivotTransform.position, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is too much of a departure from the code that I currently use, and would require a large refactor of it, while using `localPosition` was a simple and easy fix.